# Can't find how to combine DataFrames this way with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm starting to learn pandas and I am currently unable to construct the dataframe I would like to and would like some advice.

Let's say I have two DataFrames :

```
T1df:       max     min
        0   0.2     0.1
        1   0.2     0.1
        2   0.2     0.1
        3   0.2     0.1

T2df:       max     min
        0   0.4     0.3
        1   0.4     0.3
        2   0.4     0.3
        3   0.4     0.3
```

How could I merge them to end up with this shape of DataFrame?

```
T1      max   0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2 
        min   0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1
T2      max   0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4
        min   0.3  0.3  0.3  0.3
```

Comment: Have a look into [transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) `df.T` and [multiindexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html?highlight=multiindex#pandas.MultiIndex).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) by `axis=1` with `keys` parameter and then traspose by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) for `MultiIndex in index`:

```
df = pd.concat([T1df, T2df], axis=1, keys=('T1','T2')).T
print (df)
          0    1    2    3
T1 max  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.2
   min  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1
T2 max  0.4  0.4  0.4  0.4
   min  0.3  0.3  0.3  0.3
```